# Remove the last character of each string in array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array with strings in which I want to remove the last character. How can I make it possible to remove the last character for all strings that I have in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `.map()` to get a new array and for each item do a `.slice(0,-1)` to remove the last char.

```js
const array = ['abcd', '1234', 'cde', 'dot.']
const withoutLastChar = array.map(string => string.slice(0, -1));

console.log(withoutLastChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used this way

```js
const array = ['ab', 'aabb', 'ba', 'bbaa'];

const removingLastChar = array.map(string => string.substring(0, string.length - 1));

 console.log({ removingLastChar });
```